# Is it secure to use so many iterations of AES-CBC as a KDF so that it's slow even using AES-NI?

Tags: aes, key-derivation

Note: This is not the same as [Multiple iterations of AES for key derivation?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10023/multiple-iterations-of-aes-for-key-derivation).

Almost everyone has AES-NI nowadays - when building a cryptographic application, is is possible to leverage this to create a kdf that is about as slow for the attacker to attempt a single key on a single CPU as it is for the user to derive one key?

Also, is it possible to feed the last block of AES-CBC as the key of the next round of encryption over the rest of the ciphertext to make it memory-hard, and avoid encrypt-one-block-at-a-time-many-times attacks, as the entire ciphertext needs to be in memory?

Essentially, key derivation would work something like this, just a lot more times:
[image]

Comment: so you are going to start with encrypting n blocks of 128 bits in CBC mode, and then using last block ciphertext as key to encrypt n-1 of ciphertext. what is your rough estimate that n should be? Because this will dictate how much it resist against bruteforce like other KDF.

Comment: About 16K-32K iterations interactively

Comment: Just implemented it... 32K is painfully slow. I'd say 16K iterations.

Comment: for 32K iterations, what is the length of initial stream of 0's? and how much time is it taking?

Comment: Length would be half a megabyte. It doesn't end, at least on my very slow but AES-NI enabled laptop... 16K iterations takes about 7 seconds, 8K iterations takes about 2 seconds. According to my calculations, 16K iterations should lead to about 2GB total of encryption.

Comment: for an initial stream of n block of 0's, you will perform (n-1) CBC Encryption cals on block length of n,  then n-1, then n-2.... until you are left with 2 blocks. so in total (n(n+1)/2)-1 block encryption operations will be performed. Depending upon your choice of delay, requirement of ram, speed of underlying hardware, you can compute how large n should be. Keep in mind how FPGAs can work against such scheme? You should always consider to use the standards.

Comment: Yeah, the number of blocks in total is 134,225,921 which roughly equates to about 2GB. I know; just making something for fun ;) was wondering how resilient it would be against dedicated hardware

Answer (score 4):

Here's an answer that takes your question down a different path. [RFC 2898, "PKCS #5: Password-Based Cryptography Specification: Version 2.0"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898) is the document that defines the PBKDF2 function, in section 5.2.  Although PBDKF2 is normally instantiated with HMAC, the spec says that *any pseudorandom function (PRF) may be used*, with the implicit proviso that the PRF must accept variable-length keys (since the password is used as the key).

[RFC 4615, "The Advanced Encryption Standard-Cipher-based Message Authentication Code-Pseudo-Random Function-128 (AES-CMAC-PRF-128) Algorithm for the Internet Key Exchange Protocol (IKE)"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4615) defines such a variable-length key PRF on top of [AES-CMAC (RFC 4493)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4493):

> The AES-CMAC-PRF-128 algorithm is identical to AES-CMAC defined in [RFC4493] except that the 128-bit key length restriction is removed.

CMAC itself is a CBC-like mode that was designed to fix the shortcomings of the CBC MAC (which is only secure for fixed-length message spaces).

So by plugging in those reasonably standard components together you get an AES-based password-based KDF that is a bit different from your diagram but you might find close enough for your purposes.

Comment: It seems like unless you do successive iterations of the MAC it is relatively fast. However, if you do successive iterations of the MAC, it is not very memory-heavy. Are you sure the AES CMAC is bruteforce-resistant?

Comment: The iterations come from the PBKDF2 construction itself, which takes an iteration count as an argument. It's certainly not memory-heavy. It's simply not obviously worse than PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-1 or similar, that's about all I'd claim.